# Breaking a binary file into smaller parts in R

Tags: r, binary

I have several large files that I would like to turn into binary. Once it is in binary, I would like to make each piece smaller than 5GB. So however many that may be, all exist as objects in R.

I'm not exactly sure where to begin with this but generally I have via psuedocode.

```
file <- ***FILE PATH****

binFile <- writeBin(file,con)

# loop through length of 'binFile' until file.size() = 5000000 then write to a list, continue with the rest and repeat til the whole file is complete.

#Then each item in the list can be called.
```

If it is easier to write them to my local as smaller binary files that can also work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split a large file into several chunks without loading the whole file into memory. Here's a function that will do that.

You supply it with the path to your big file, the path to the directory in which you would like the chunks to be saved, and the maximum chunk size.

The files will all be saved with the name of the big file plus the chunk number, and the file type `.bin`.

The original file is left unchanged.

If you want to read the chunks into R as binary, you can just read them with `readBin`

```r
chop_file <- function(bigfile, save_path, chunk_size)
{
  con <- file(bigfile, "rb")
  pos <- 0
  file_size <- file.size(bigfile)
  chunk_no <- 1
  filenames <- sapply(strsplit(bigfile, "/"), function(x) x[length(x)])
  filenames <- gsub("[.]", "", filenames)

  while(pos < file_size)
  {
    seek(con, pos)
    data <- readBin(con, "raw", chunk_size)
    pos  <- seek(con, 0)
    writeBin(data, paste0(save_path, filenames, chunk_no, ".bin"))
    chunk_no <- chunk_no + 1
  }

  close(con)
  message(paste("  File", bigfile, "split into", chunk_no - 1, "chunks"))
}
```

For example, if I have a single large binary file in the following directory:

```
dir("C:/Users/Me/pdfs/")
# [1] bigfile.pdf
```

And I wish to chunk it into 1MB pieces in the empty directory `C:/Users/Me/chunks/`, I do:

```
chop_file("C:/Users/Me/pdfs/bigfile.pdf", "C:/Users/Me/chunks/", 1e6)
#>  File C:/Users/Me/pdfs/bigfile.pdf split into 10 chunks
```

And now

```
dir("C:/Users/Me/chunks/")
#> [1] "bigfilepdf1.bin"  "bigfilepdf2.bin"  "bigfilepdf3.bin"  "bigfilepdf4.bin" 
#> [5] "bigfilepdf5.bin"  "bigfilepdf6.bin"  "bigfilepdf7.bin"  "bigfilepdf8.bin" 
#> [9] "bigfilepdf9.bin"  "bigfilepdf10.bin"
```

If you wanted to stitch all these back together again in memory, you could do this:

```r
data <- list()
files <- dir("C:/Users/Me/chunks/")
for(i in seq_along(files)) data[[i]] <- readBin(files[i], "raw", 10e6)
data <- do.call("c", data)
```

Then `data` will contain all the bytes of the original file as a raw vector.

```
identical(data, readBin("C:/Users/Me/pdfs/bigfile.pdf", "raw", 1e7))
#> [1] TRUE
```

If you would rather process the chunks in memory instead of writing them to disk, you can simplify things a bit:

```r
chop_file_to_list <- function(bigfile, chunk_size)
{
  con <- file(bigfile, "rb")
  pos <- 0
  file_size <- file.size(bigfile)
  chunk_no <- 1
  data <- list()

  while(pos < file_size)
  {
    seek(con, pos)
    data[[chunk_no]] <- readBin(con, "raw", chunk_size)
    pos  <- seek(con, 0)
    chunk_no <- chunk_no + 1
  }

  close(con)
  return(data)
}
```

Comment: This is excellent; what if I didn't want to physically save the chunks? That is, what if I want them to only exist in R and when I am done running the function they are deleted?

Comment: Also, having all the parts, is there an easy way I can put them back together?

Comment: In that case Johnny, instead of writing them to a file with writeBin, you process the chunk at that point. So instead of writeBin(data) you would have `my_processing_function(data)`. You might need a list to store intermediate results as well. @JohnnyThomas

Comment: @JohnnyThomas do you mean put them back together on disk or in memory in R?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean? could you update your code to so I can see this in action? And putting them together in memory in R, which already exists as the original file but this is more of a curiosity thing as to whether it is possible to take the bin files and sew them together to look like the orginal

Comment: Saving it to a list would be great now that I think about it